# PHP - combine multiple arrays (only occurrences of all arrays)

Tags: php, arrays

Is there any php function that can return occurrences of all provided arrays (that are in all arrays)?

Example:

```
$array1 = array(1, 2, 3);
$array2 = array(1, 2, 4, 5, 6);
$array3 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

func_i_am_looking_for($array1, $array2, $array3);
//retrun array(1, 2);
```

Comment: If you are looking for an array function, glance the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try with [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/array_intersect)

```
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2, $array3);
```

Comment: Yes that's it, thank you! Didn't know how to name what I need. Will flag as correct answer in 10 minutes.